# How to calculate 95% CI for a random effect?

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval, mathematical-statistics

The R code "intervals()" gives confidence intervals for fixed effects only in a mixed model.

*Is there a reason why only fixed effects' confidence intervals are provided?

*Is there any way to get confidence intervals for random effects as well?

Comment: What would you like confidence intervals *of*?  (Random effects are usually expressed as standard deviations or variances.)

Comment: Have you read [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1016/j.jml.2007.12.005)?

Answer (score 1):

I think `confint(model_name)` provides the 95% CI for the standard deviation of the random effect.